# Add a custom network to the gnosis-safe UI

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I want to use gnosis safe contracts and UI on a private network

Here is some context and what I did:

I deployed the [safe-react](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react) app to get started and understand how the UI works

Then I deployed the [safe-contracts](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts) on my private network

Now I'm trying to modify the app in order to add my custom network to the UI, using [safe-infrastructure](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure), since the app fetches networks from config-service / transaction-service

But I have some issues and can't get it to work properly:

- Firstly, I think that the README is not up-to-date, because step 0 is not optional but mandatory
- When using docker compose, some containers are crashing and I need to restart them multiple times
- When connecting to http://localhost:8000/cfg/admin/ with root/admin, there is an additional field for OTP Token, I don't know how to get it
- And other issues when creating superuser

Is there an official way or something to correctly add a private network to the UI ?

Thanks!